# Windows drivers for MacBookPro 5,1

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I'm trying to install windows 2k8 R2  on an old MacBook Pro (5,1). Thats the first unibody macbook with core2duo.

The harddrive did crash so I don't have any option to use bootcamp to retrieve my drivers. Any advice where I can find the driver package for a 64 bit windows operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the appropriate drivers on http://support.apple.com/downloads/#bootcamp.